# How to make CheckBoxList Validator

Tags: validation

I have Checkboxlist and i can't give it required field validator or custom validator.
it gives me runtime exception.

Language : Vb.net with asp.net

Comment: what language are you using?  Maybe post a code snippet and the error text.

Comment: Please be much more specific.  Language, technologies, and all those are important because right now there is no way to answer your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no cannot apply required field validator on the checkbox list

but you can use custom validator to validate it

for the custom validator to work you have to create your own function on server or client side for validation and one more thing when you are using custom validator there no need to pass value in the `controltovalidate` property

Comment: I tried custom validator but with controltovalidate prperty. i will check without it.

Comment: if you are using customvlidator than no need to set controltovalidate property

Answer (score 10):

with jQuery and ASP.Net CustomValidator:

```
function validateCheckBoxList(sender, args) {
    args.IsValid = ($("#CheckBoxListId :checked").length > 0);
}

<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required!" ClientValidationFunction="validateCheckBoxList"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t8qj4tqb/

Comment: I tried this but couldn't get it to work. The length always returns zero even when the checkboxlist has items selected in it. Help!

Comment: Are you sure the selector can find the CheckBoxList? Maybe the id of the CheckBoxList is all messed up because of ASP.Net AutoID. If you use `#` as the selector make sure it matches exactly. You could also use '$("[id$=CheckBoxListId] :checkbox:checked")' to avoid the AutoID problem.

Comment: Thanks Homer, I'll give that a try and let you know how it works.

Answer (score 4):

Its working and here is the code

```
function CheckBoxListValidator(source, arguments) {
            var Control;
            Control = document.getElementById("CKlistVehicleBodies").getElementsByTagName("input");
            var check = false;
            if (eval(Control)) {
                for (var i = 0; i < Control.length; i++) {
                    if (Control[i].tagName == 'INPUT') {

                        if (Control[i].checked) {
                            check = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (!check)
                    arguments.IsValid = false;
                else
                    arguments.IsValid = true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This one is FREE, comes with source code, and is just like the other .NET controls – drop it on a page, pick the checkbox list control to validate and you get client side and server side validation. It also works with AJAX. It even lets you pick a minimum and maximum number of checkboxes that have to be checked or can be checked.

http://www.aboutfortunate.com/Component-Library/Checkboxlist-Required-Field-Validator.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I use the skmValidators to validate check boxes.

[Creating Validator Controls for the CheckBox and CheckBoxList](https://web.archive.org/web/20210304131838/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092006-1.aspx)